# Are there any packages to import bibxml into (la)tex?

Tags: import, xml, export, mathml, xmltex

While I was able to find several packages to export bibtex to bibxml, and even the whole latex stuff to xml/mathml, I could not find anything in the opposite direction.

Of course it would be great to be able importing mathml into (la)tex, but if this is too much to ask, maybe there is at least something to handle bibliography?

I found something called xmltex but the only documentation I found looks quite frightening for a lame user like me. It seems to require scary things like configuration, building formats, etc.

Can anybody explain in the for dummies style how to use xmltex? Or maybe there are some more user friendly packages?

Comment: It is best to use specialized tools for XML transformations, like XSLT. There are for example templates for MathML to LaTeX conversion. Regarding tools that have direct support in LaTeX, there is LuaXML package for LuaTeX. It can be used for process XML files using Lua (note: I am the author). [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/548484/2891) is small example for importing small subset of MathML to LaTeX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are the [Bibxmlutils](https://incenp.org/dvlpt/bibxmlutils.html) utilities that include `bibxmlto` which can generate a `.bib` file. It looks like these are distributed as source only for most platforms, although there are Slackware and Windows binary packages available.