# How can I automatically elaborate data from XML file?

Tags: automation, xml

I have an XML document with elements I must use to create a LaTeX document. Is there a way to automatically get each of these elements and for each of them, execute some LaTeX commands?

To make it clearer, suppose I have articles stored like this:

```xml
<article title="Article title" author='The Author'>
    <section title="Section title">
        <body>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
            consectetur adipiscing elit.
        </body>
    </section>
    <image source="image/path/foo.png" />
    <section title=”Another section title">
        <body>
            Nam dui ligula, fringilia a,
            euismod sodales, sollicitudin
            vel, wisi.
        </body>
    </section>
</article>
```

and that I want to create a LaTeX document that when compiled automatically creates the same output I'd have if I manually did the following for each article:

```
\chapter{Article title}
by \emph{The Author}

\section{Section title}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consectetur adipiscing elit.

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image/path/foo.png}

\section{Another section title}
Nam dui ligula, fringilia a,
euismod sodales, sollicitudin
vel, wisi.
```

I think something like `csvsimple` package would do the work, but I couldn't find it. However, at the moment I have only the XML document, so I can try every possible solution without loosing any already done work.

Comment: Hope you are looking for something like `XMLTeX` else try with the conversion from `XML` to `LaTeX` by using `XSLT`...

Answer (score 3):

You can use my LuaXML package, which as it's name suggests can process XML documents using LuaTeX. I would create a simple Lua module that can process your document, using modified version of code from my answer about [Mathml to LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/548484/2891) processing. This is the library, `transform-xml.lua`:

```lua
-- adapted code from https://github.com/michal-h21/luaxml-mathml
--
local domobject = require "luaxml-domobject"

-- we need to define different actions for XML elements. The default action is
-- to just process child elements and return the result
local function default_action(element)
  return process_children(element)
end

-- use template string to place the processed children
local function simple_content(s)
  return function(element)
    local content = process_children(element)
    -- process attrubutes
    -- attribute should be marked as @{name}
    local expanded = s:gsub("@{(.-)}", function(name)
      return element:get_attribute(name) or ""
    end)
    return string.format(expanded, content)
  end
end

local function get_child_element(element, count)
  -- return specified child element 
  local i = 0
  for _, el in ipairs(element:get_children()) do
    -- count elements 
    if el:is_element() then
      -- return the desired numbered element
      i = i + 1
      if i == count then return el end
    end
  end
end

-- actions for particular elements
local actions = {
  
}

-- add more complicated action
local function add_custom_action(name, fn)
  actions[name] = fn
end

-- normal actions
local function add_action(name, template)
  actions[name] = simple_content(template)
end

-- convert Unicode characters to TeX sequences
local unicodes = {
  [35] = "\\#",
  [38] = "\\&",
  [60] = "\\textless{}",
  [62] = "\\textgreater{}",
  [92] = "\\textbackslash{}",
  [123] = "\\{",
  [125] = "\\}"
}

local function process_text(text)
  local t = {}
  -- process all Unicode characters and find if they should be replaced
  for _, char in utf8.codes(text) do
    -- construct new string with replacements or original char
    t[#t+1] = unicodes[char] or utf8.char(char)
  end
  return table.concat(t)
end

function process_children(element)
  -- accumulate text from children elements
  local t = {}
  -- sometimes we may get text node
  if type(element) ~= "table" then return element end
  for i, elem in ipairs(element:get_children()) do
    if elem:is_text() then
      -- concat text
      t[#t+1] = process_text(elem:get_text())
    elseif elem:is_element() then
      -- recursivelly process child elements
      t[#t+1] = process_tree(elem)
    end
  end
  return table.concat(t)
end


function process_tree(element)
  -- find specific action for the element, or use the default action
  local element_name = element:get_element_name()
  local action = actions[element_name] or default_action
  return action(element)
end

function parse_xml(content)
  -- parse XML string and process it
  local dom = domobject.parse(content)
  -- start processing of DOM from the root element
  -- return string with TeX content
  return process_tree(dom:root_node())
end

local function load_file(filename)
  local f = io.open(filename, "r")
  local content = f:read("*all")
  f:close()
  return parse_xml(content)
end


function print_tex(content)
  -- we need to replace "\n" characters with calls to tex.sprint
  for s in content:gmatch("([^\n]*)") do
    tex.sprint(s)
  end
end


local M = {
  parse_xml = parse_xml,
  process_children = process_children,
  print_tex = print_tex,
  add_action = add_action,
  add_custom_action = add_custom_action,
  simple_content = simple_content,
  load_file = load_file
}

return M
```

I will not describe it in much detail, as it is basically the same as [from my other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/548484/2891), it is only more general.

The main function it provides is `transform_xml.add_action`. It takes two parameters, the first is name of the element, the second is a TeX template that will be inserted in your document.

The template can insert text from all children elements using `%s` text. You should use it in all elements that can contain any text. Attributes can be accessed using `@{attribute name}` placeholder.

Sample template may look like this:

```
xmltransform.add_action("section", [[\section{@{title}}
%s
\par]])
```

Note that we use `[[ ... ]]` to specify the template, in order to make it easier to input newlines and backslashes. You also need to use `\par` command when you want to insert paragraph.

We can specify necessary actions in custom TeX package, `myarticle.sty`:

```
\ProvidesPackage{myarticle}
\RequirePackage{luacode}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{xparse}


\begin{luacode*}
xmltransform = require "transform_xml.lua" 


xmltransform.add_action("article", [[
\chapter{@{title}}
by \emph{@{author}}\par

%s
]])

xmltransform.add_action("section", [[\section{@{title}}
%s
\par]])

xmltransform.add_action("image", '\\includegraphics{@{source}}')

function article_load(filename)
  local transformed = xmltransform.load_file(filename)
  if transformed then
    xmltransform.print_tex(transformed)
  else
    tex.sprint("Error in parsing of the XML file " .. filename)
  end
end

\end{luacode*}


\NewDocumentCommand\processarticle{m}{%
  \directlua{article_load("#1")}
}
 

\endinput
```

Actions are specified for all elements that need it (article, section, image). When no action is specified for a element, like `<body>`, it's content is just processed and inserted to the TeX document.

Package also declares a new command, `\processarticle`. It takes XML file name and process it with `transform_xml`.

We can now try a sample document:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{myarticle}
\begin{document}
\processarticle{article.xml}
\end{document}
```

And this is the resulting PDF:

[image]